# using ADO.NET to select from multiple VFP tables

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, visual-foxpro

I need to select from 2 VFP free tables on some different network locations.

I've managed to get both tables into a dataset as two DataTables and add a Relation for them.

Now I need to join them and the result to insert into a SQL server database.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you added a Relation then aren't they already joined together through that relationship?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I need to select something like SELECT SUM(t1.filed), t2.field from t1 join t2 .....

Comment: The tables in different network locations... are they totally different drive letters, or just relative paths on the same drive...

Answer (score 1):

Use two different queries to load the required subset of rows and columns from each table, upload each table individually to temp SQL server tables (using SqlBulkUpload), and then run your query in SQL against the two temp tables to create the required table.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Access to add them as linked tables. You can then read the data from .net as though it were native Access data. You might be able to create queries in Access that join the tables and then read the queries from .net too.